Is it correct to remove an escape key when decoding bytes?
I have the following small dataframe that I am passing through a decoder that decodes some byte values in the dataframe:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dict = {'trade_qualifier' : [b'\x86', b' ', b' ', b'\x02']} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict) 
def decode_bytes(df):
    col = 'trade_qualifier'
    df[col] = df[col].values.astype(np.str_).astype('O')

    return df

decode_bytes(df)

The above breaks with:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x86 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I can simply remove the backslashes in the byes so that b'\x86' -> b'x86' for example.
But I am not sure if this is the correct thing to do?
I suppose a better question may be, what does this line do?:
df[col] = df[col].values.astype(np.str_).astype('O')

My understanding is that this line is changing the type of each value in the col column to be an np.str type? Is that correct?
I apologise if this is a very basic question, I am still new to working with bytes.

What is the source of the bytes? Do you know which encoding was used?

The problem isn't the backslash, it's ASCII. ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, meaning the max value is (2^7)-1 or 127, (or 7F in hex). \x86 refers to 86 in hex, which is 134 in decimal.

df[col].map(lambda x: x.decode('Windows-1252')) would "work" with your example, but you shouldn't guess the encoding, so make sure to know which encoding you expect

Thanks for the answers guys. What did you mean by what encoding?
Does this mean how the bytes were encoded to b'\x86' in the first place?

Well, to convert bytes to strings you need to know the encoding, there are dozens of ways to encode text. If you encode the same string with different encodings (UTF-8, ISO8859-2,…) you'll get different bytes. You cannot decode bytes without knowing the encoding that was used in the first place, especially for single characters (you can try to guess for large texts)

Very eloquent explanation, thank you. I'll try to find out what encoding was used.
